# First n characters of string or whole string; without SubscriptOutOfBounds

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo 7, I am trying to get the first number of characters of a string, or just the whole string (if the requested number of characters exceeds the length of the string).

However, the following example results in an error, whereas I just want it to return the whole string:

```
    'abcdef' copyFrom: 1 to: 30. "=> SubscriptOutOfBounds Error"
    'abcdef' first: 30. "=> SubscriptOutOfBounds Error"
    'abcdef' first: 3. "=> 'abc'; OK"
```

Is there a method that will just return the whole string if the requested length exceeds the string length?

As a workaround, I did the following, to check first the length of the string and only send `first:` if the length exceeds the maximum length, but it's not very elegant:

```
label := aTaskbarItemMorph label size < 30 ifTrue: [ aTaskbarItemMorph label ] ifFalse: [ aTaskbarItemMorph label first: 30 ].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **String>>truncateTo:**

```
'abcdef' truncateTo: 30. "'abcdef'"
'abcdef' truncateTo: 3. "'abc'"
```

Answer (score 5):

## MethodFinder to the rescue

We should also bear in mind that for cases like this one we have the `MethodFinder` in Pharo. You use it by evaluating the examples you have. In our case

```
MethodFinder methodFor: #(('abcdef' 30) 'abcdef' ('abcdef' 3) 'abc')
```

will produce

```
"'(data1 contractTo: data2) (data1 truncateTo: data2) '"
```

which contains the already mentioned `#truncateTo:` and adds `#contractTo:`. Note that the latter implements other flavor of shortening techniques, namely

```
'abcdef' contractTo: 6 "'a...f'"
```

probably not what you want today, but a piece of information that might prove useful in the future.

---

## Syntax

The syntax of `MethodFinder` requires an `Array` of length `2 * #examples`, where each of the examples consists of a pair (*input arguments*, *result*).

Interestingly, Squeak braces make it easy to provide dynamically created examples:

```
input := 'abcdef'.
n := 1.
MethodFinder methodFor: {
     {input. input size + n}. input.
     {input. input size - n}. input allButLast
}
```

will also find `truncateTo:`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any such method by default in the `String` class or its superclasses. Your workaround is a good solution.

Alternatively a shorter workaround is to use `min:` to select either the size of the string or a limited number of characters. For example:

```
string := '123456'.
label := string first: (string size min: 5).
```

Another solution is to add an extension method to the `String` class that does what you want. So the method would be added to the `String` class but placed in your package. For example:

```
String>>atMost: numberOfElement
    ^ self size < numberOfElement 
        ifTrue: [ self ] 
        ifFalse: [ self first: numberOfElement ]
```

Then the following would work:

```
string := '123456'.
string atMost: 2.  "'12'"
string atMost: 10. "'123456'"
```

When adding extension method you could add a prefix to their name to avoid possible conflicts if for example the method `atMost:` would be added in Pharo later or if another package would also define such an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple expression that will bring what you want:

```
aString readStream next: n
```